# Give a function of three variable such that the paraboloid is a level surface of the function

Tags: calculus

Pretty basic question.

The question asks to give a function of three variable $F(x,y,x)$ such that the paraboloid $z=x^2 + y^2$ is a level surface of the function $F$.

I am a little confused by what they mean. Is this the same as finding the tangent of the function? What exactly am I supposed to look for here?

Comment: Do you know what level surface is?

Comment: @Ennar apparently not

Comment: Where did you get this question from? If it's a textbook, I'm sure it will include the definition. I'll write an answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Level sets are sets of the form

$$\{x\in\mathbb R^{n}\mid f(x) = c\} = f^{-1}\{c\}$$

for some function $f\colon\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ and some constant $c\in\mathbb R$. For example, unit circle is a level set:

$$\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2 = 1\}$$ for function $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ and constant $c = 1$.

You have paraboloid, though, satisfying the equation $x^2+y^2-z = 0$, i.e. it is the level set

$$\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\mid x^2+y^2-z = 0\}$$ for function $F(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2-z$ and constant $c = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite $z=x^2+y^2$ as, for example, $x^2+y^2-z=0$. Now, just call the LHS of that equation a function of three variables: $F(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z$. Then your paraboloid is the surface $F(x,y,z)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

> A level set of a function is a set that consists of the preimages of *one point* of  the range of that function.

For example, if we are given the function $f(x) = x^2$, then the level set of $1$ is $\{1,-1\}$, and that of four is $\{2,-2\}$.

Here, you are being asked to find a function whose level set at some point is the set $\{x^2+y^2-z = 0\}$. Literally the answer stares you in the face : by construction, this is the level set of the function $F(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2 - z$ at the point $0$.

Another way of modifying this would be to take $F(x,y,z) = \frac{(x^2+y^2) + 1}{z+1}$ wherever well defined. You can check that the level set at the point $1$ of this function also is the given paraboloid.